# Responsive Main Menu Not Expanding

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, responsive

I'm tasked with maintaining a website but have limited experience in advanced aspects of CSS, coding, etc.

The site is hosted on Wordpress and is located [here](http://icarek9.com).

When the hamburger is clicked, the menu isn't displayed.  Would anyone happen to have any insight into what's causing my issue?

Comment: The hamburger?  Has someone eaten the hamburger?  I can't find the hamburger.

Answer (score 1):

You have an element in `.headbg` that is overlapping the hamburger.

You can address it by applying a higher z-index to `#top-bar` than is in `.headbg`. Simply give `#top-bar` a `z-index: 1003;` (to be higher than `#header a.logo`, which is `1002`) and that will make the links in `#top-bar` be on top of `.headbg`, while still allowing you to click the link in `.headbg`.

Comment: I agree adding z-index to #top-bar is, I guess, a better option that what I suggested.

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff maybe... they could also work on the layout and size that `#header a.logo` down to match the size it is on screen. Right now it's taking up more space than it should, contributing to it overlapping other elements (like the hamburger menu).

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your link

```
<a href="http://icarek9.com" class="logo"><h1>iCareK9 Dog Boarding &amp; DayCare      </h1></a>
```

with a style of

```
#header a.logo {
    z-index: 1002;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

that renders above your button.

You could lower that link on the page, for example : (10px should be enough)

```
#header a.logo {
    z-index: 1002;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 10px
}
```

or could increase the z-index of your button to something higher than 1002, so it will render above your link

```
.navbar-toggle {
    margin-right: 0;
    z-index: 1003
}
```

Looking at your browser inspector you could see the stacking of your elements. Especially in Firefox you could use this feature : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/3D_View